# How to ensure that string refers to an image using typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a `ReactJs project` in which I get the image path through a `require` in an object. This object has a type and the img property receives a string. It works, but the problem is that  TS can't know whether this string is an image or any other thing:

```
type Obj = {
  img: string
}

// That's correct
const obj1 = {
  img: require('./../img-path-here')
}

// That's not correct, but TS doesn't complain
const obj2 = {
  img: './../img-path-here'
}

// That's not correct either, but TS doesn't complain
const obj3 = {
  img: 'any string'
}
```

Is there a way to type img so TS would know which value is really valid?

Comment: you can use a type alias to define a custom type for the img property that represents a string that refers to an image file.
`type ImagePath = string & { __imagePath: true };

type Obj = {
  img: ImagePath
}

const obj1: Obj = {
  img: require('./../img-path-here') as ImagePath
}`

i hope you will get a hint. let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: I don't get it. is the `img` field a base64 encoded image or is it itself a path to an image?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to wrap that `require` in a function which does some runtime type checking. `require` returns `any` anyway.

If the type of the `img` field is a datauri then it is simple. You can express that as a type:

```js
type Base64Image = `data:image/${'jpeg'|'png'|'gif'};base64,${string}`
const base64ImageDecoder = /^data:image\/(jpeg|png|gif);base64,/;

const requireImage = (path: string) => {
    const data = require(path);
    if(typeof data === 'string' && base64ImageDecoder.test(data)) {
        return data as Base64Image
    } else throw Error(`"${path}" doesn't point to a Base64Image`)
}

type Obj = {
    img: Base64Image
}

const obj1: Obj = {
    img: requireImage('./../img-path-here')
}

const obj2: Obj = {
    // @ts-expect-error: not Base64Image
    img: './../img-path-here'
}
```

If it's a path, the way you check whether or not it's valid at runtime is up to you and your level of paranoia. Maybe you only want to make sure `require` is used, then you can skip the check, but it's fundamentally the same process:

```js
type ImagePath = string & { _tag: 'ImagePath' }
const isImagePath = (data: unknown) => /* you do you */;

const requireImagePath = (path: string) => {
    const data = require(path);
    if(isImagePath(data)) {
        return data as ImagePath
    } else throw Error(`"${path}" doesn't point to an ImagePath`)
}


type Obj = {
    img: ImagePath
}

const obj1: Obj = {
    img: requireImagePath('./../img-path-here')
}

const obj2: Obj = {
    // @ts-expect-error: not ImagePath
    img: './../img-path-here'
}
```